# Use a database to populate a mobile app with information

Tags: database, actionscript-3, flash

I am writing a mobile app using Flash and ActionScript 3 and I am looking to populate a page using a backend database.

Here is an image that explains what I would like to populate it with.

[image: App Screen]

I have made this page in ActionScript and called in an image from the library for C and then I have made a dynamic text field for A, B and D.

However I would ideally like to have a separate "load" of information for each of 15 different cars (the G Wagon being just one of them) and then a car selection screen takes you to this page.

I have access to a database which I can use however I am at beginner level with this and would not know 1. how to put the information I want to be populated into the database and 2. how to connect the database to my app.

[image: Database]

So in the original image there is 4 bits of information that will be taken from the database to the app. And there are 15 of these screens each featuring a different image and information.

If anyone can give me some assistance I would be amazingly grateful!!

Thank you!

---

Here is the code I'm using to build the above screenshot at the moment.

```
package com.james.mercedes //Location of the package! 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.display.Stage;

import flash.display.StageAlign;

import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

import flash.display.StageQuality;

import flash.display.SimpleButton;

import flash.events.Event;

import flash.events.TextEvent;

import flash.text.*;

//import assets from the library
import Background;
import CarImage;
import BackButton;
import CarName;
import CarDescription;
import InformationTable;
//import CarNameText;
//import CarDescriptionText;
//import InformationTableTitleText;

//import classes in our package
//import com.james.mercedes;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Background color of the stage
[SWF(backgroundColor="0x000000")]
//chosen the actionscript file
public class carInfo extends MovieClip 
{

//make an instance of the asset
private var background:MovieClip = new Background();
private var carImage:MovieClip = new CarImage();
private var backButton:MovieClip = new BackButton();
private var carName:MovieClip = new CarName();
private var carDescription:MovieClip = new CarDescription();
private var informationTable:MovieClip = new InformationTable();
//private var carNameText:MovieClip = new CarNameText();
//private var carDescriptionText:MovieClip = new CarDescriptionText();
//private var informationTableTitleText:MovieClip = new    InformationTableTitleText();

var CarNameText: TextField = new TextField;


//main file to set up application
public function carInfo() 
{

//wait for the stage to load before doing any calculations - good practice

addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init )

}
function init( e:Event ):void
{

//trace( " Here " );

//setup stage for mobile device

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

//doesn't shrink or enlarge (no_scale)
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

stage.quality = StageQuality.HIGH;


//call upon a public class of static variables ( refer to folder structure to     locate Constants.as )

stage.stageWidth = Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH;

stage.stageHeight = Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT;


//add the linked instance from library to the stage

addChild ( background );
addChild ( carImage );
addChild ( backButton );
addChild ( carName );
addChild ( carDescription );
addChild ( informationTable );
addChild ( carNameText );
addChild ( carDescriptionText );
addChild ( informationTableTitleText );

//scale accordingly before positioning it


//background.scaleX *= Constants.SCREEN_SCALE;

//background.scaleY *= Constants.SCREEN_SCALE;


//position to a fixed x and y


background.x = 0;
background.y = 0;

carImage.x = 0;
carImage.y = 0;

backButton.x = 18.30;
backButton.y = 19.90;

carName.x = 194.55;
carName.y = 378.85;

carDescription.x = 12.55;
carDescription.y = 432.65;

informationTable.x = 47.55;
informationTable.y = 833.65;

carNameText.x = 204.90;
carNameText.y = 370.40;

carDescriptionText.x = 43.85;
carDescriptionText.y = 453.90;

informationTableTitleText.x = 168.85;
informationTableTitleText.y = 806.20;


}


}

}
```

Comment: It's a bit broad.   Do you have any database experience?  You are using AIR presumably?   You can either use a local SQL database or XML file or serialized data file (if your database is just a static dump of data),  or (assuming you want the database updateable by some administrator) a web service of some sort that can access a database and send the data on to the app.   Something like Azure Mobile Services if your not keen on writing your own

Comment: Sorry my bad haha I'm pretty new to this DB stuff only last month or so.

Yep I'm using AIR for iOS. 

Which of those 3 options, Local SQL, CML or Serialized Data File is simplest to implement?

The data doesnt need to be updated at all after the first release.

Comment: XML would probably be easiest.  You can easily change it in any text editor and it's very easy to parse out data in AS3 from an XML file.   If you could update your question with the code your using to populate the areas of you screenshot, that would be helpful for someone to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the app (any AIR or swf application) can send data to the backend by regular form POST (like an html form).  The app can also load a php page and read its content.  So the app POSTs data to a php page and loads its response (XML).  You should always use XML to send data from backend to the app - encapsulates them (RESTful).

Or you can pass data to PHP in the url (querystring) and load the response.

Example: getCars.php?sMake=Ford=sModel=Explorer - getCars.php could use sMake and sModel to query and write the results in xml.  The app loads the xml.

So your xml will look something like:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <itemName>![CDATA[<G Wagon]]></itemName>
        <itemDescription><![CDATA[The Mercedes-Benz G-Class or ...]]></itemDescription>
        <itemPic>![CDATA[../images/pic_g_wagon.jpg]]></itemPic>
    </item>
</items>
```

You'll find tons of code examples for doing each part of this like writing and parsing XML or handling POSTs with php.

republicofcode.com has great tutorials on basics like XML parsing.

gotoandlearn.com has higher level video tutorials.